# Ayuda, error de compilacion usando string dentro de un switch en c++

Tags: c++, string

les saludo, recien empiezo a programar y me encuentro con este problema "[Error] 'binario1' was not declared in this scope" es un string dentro de un switch, un string parecio fuera del switch me funciona, pero dentro no, si me pueden ayudar.el codigo no esta terminado solo, solo es que me trabe en esta parte.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (){

int opcion;
/* string para menu*/
string menu1,menu2,menu3,menu4,salir;
menu1 = "1. MENU BINARIO";
menu2 = "2. MENU DECIMAL";
menu3 = "3. MENU HEXADECIMAL";
menu4 = "4. MENU OCTAL";    
salir = "5. SALIR";
cout<<menu1<<endl<<menu2<<endl<<menu3<<endl<<menu4<<endl<<salir<<endl;
/*bucle dowhile que solo elija una opcion valida*/
do {
cout<<"Elija un menu :";cin>>opcion;
} while (opcion<1 || opcion>5);
/*switch general de menu*/  
switch (opcion){
    case 1 : {// estas llaves las puse por que me tiraba otro error si no las ponia.
             int opcion2;
             std::string binario1,binario2,binario3,salir2;// lo mismo con el std:: delante del string y cout.
             binario1 = "1. Pasar de binario a decimal";
             binario2 = "2. Pasar de binario a hexadecimal";
             binario3 = "3. Pasar de binario a octal";
             salir2 = "4. salir";}
             std::cout<<"MENU BINARIO"<<endl<<binario1<<endl<<binario2<<endl<<binario3<<endl<<salir2<<endl;
             /*bucle dowhile que solo elija una opcion valida*/
             do{
             cout<<"Digite una opcion :";cin>>opcion2;
                }while (opcion2<1 || opcion2>4);
             switch (opcion2){
                case 1 :
                case 2 :
                case 3 :
                case 4 :
                defualt : break;
             }break;
    case 2 : int opcion3;
             {
             std::string decimal1,decimal2,decimal3,salir3; 
             decimal1 = "1. Pasar de decimal a binario";
             decimal2 = "2. Pasar de decimal a hexadecimal";
             decimal3 = "3. Pasar de decimal a octal";
             salir3 = "4. Salir";}
             std::cout<<"MENU DECIMAL"<<endl<<decimal1<<endl<<decimal2<<endl<<decimal3<<endl<<salir3<<endl;
             /*bucle dowhile interno para que solo elija una opcion*/
             do{
             cout<<"Digite una opcion :";cin>>opcion3;
                }while (opcion3<1 || opcion3>4);
                /*Switch interno case 2*/
                switch (opcion3){
                    case 1 :
                    case 2 :
                    case 3 :
                    case 4 :
                    defualt :;
                }break;
    case 3 : int opcion4;
             { // estas llaves las puse por que me tiraba otro error si no las ponia.
             std::string hexa1,hexa2,hexa3,salir4; 
             hexa1 = "1. Pasar de hexadecimal a binario";
             hexa2 = "2. Pasar de hexadecimal a decimal";
             hexa3 = "3. Pasar de hexadecimal a octal";
             salir4 = "4. Salir";}
             std::cout<<"MENU HEXADECIMAL"<<endl<<hexa1<<endl<<hexa2<<endl<<hexa3<<endl<<salir4<<endl;
             /*bucle dowhile interno para que solo elija una opcion*/
             do{
             cout<<"Digite una opcion :";cin>>opcion4;
                }while (opcion4<1 || opcion4>4);
                /*Switch interno case 3*/
                switch (opcion4){
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    default:;
                }break;
    case 4 :int opcion5; 
            {
             std::string octal1,octal2,octal3,salir5;
             octal1 = "1. Pasar de octal a binario";
             octal2 = "2. Pasar de octal a decimal";
             octal3 = "3. Pasar de octal a hexadecimal";
             salir5 = "4. Salir";}
             std::cout<<"MENU OCTAL"<<endl<<octal1<<endl<<octal2<<endl<<octal3<<endl<<salir5<<endl;
             /*bucle dowhile interno para que solo elija una opcion*/
             do{
                cout<<"Digite una opcion :";cin>>opcion5;
             }while (opcion5<1 || opcion5>4);
             /*Switch interno case 3*/
             switch (opcion5){
                case 1 :
                case 2 :
                case 3 :
                case 4 :
                default :;
             }break;
    case 5 : return (exit);
    default :;
}

return 0;
system ("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porfavor corrijanme si estoy mirando mal :)

1. Tu código está muy desarreglado, debes aprender un poco a dar formato (indentado), haces llamadas extrañas y en tus estructuras switch llamas a `defualt` no a `default`.
2. Dentro de `case 2` y `case 4` declaras una variable fuera de las llaves, cuando el compilador espera una instrucción `break`, tiene un `}` fuera de lugar a la derecha de la asignacion de `salir3` al igual que el `case 1`, `case 3` y `case 4`.
3. Ya estas llamando a `using namespace std;` por lo que no tienes que usar `std::` en cada definición.
4. Si usas `std::cout` recuerda tambien usar `std::endl`, pero como mecioné en el punto 3, ya estas llamando al `namespace std`.
5. No puedes llamar a `system("pause");` luego de la instruccion `return 0;` al llegar a `return` ya el la función termina y por ende la ejecución del programa tambien (al ser la función `main`).

---

El codigo arreglado (a mi me funcionó, he cambiado `system("pause")` por `cin.get()` debido a que ando en linux):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    int opcion;

    string menu1, menu2, menu3, menu4, salir;

    menu1 = "1. MENU BINARIO";
    menu2 = "2. MENU DECIMAL";
    menu3 = "3. MENU HEXADECIMAL";
    menu4 = "4. MENU OCTAL";    
    salir = "5. SALIR";

    cout << menu1 << endl << menu2 << endl << menu3 << endl << menu4 << endl << salir << endl;

    do {
        cout << "Elija un menu :"; cin >> opcion;
    } while (opcion < 1 || opcion > 5);

    // Main switch
    switch (opcion) 
    {
        case 1 : 
        {
            int opcion2;
            string binario1, binario2, binario3, salir2;

            binario1 = "1. Pasar de binario a decimal";
            binario2 = "2. Pasar de binario a hexadecimal";
            binario3 = "3. Pasar de binario a octal";
            salir2 = "4. salir";

            cout << "MENU BINARIO" << endl << binario1 << endl << binario2 << endl << binario3 << endl << salir2 << endl;

            do {
                cout<<"Digite una opcion :"; cin >> opcion2;
            } while (opcion2 < 1 || opcion2 > 4);

            switch (opcion2) {
                case 1 :
                case 2 :
                case 3 :
                case 4 :
                default : break;
            } 
        } break;

        case 2 : 
        {
            int opcion3;
            string decimal1, decimal2, decimal3, salir3;

            decimal1 = "1. Pasar de decimal a binario";
            decimal2 = "2. Pasar de decimal a hexadecimal";
            decimal3 = "3. Pasar de decimal a octal";
            salir3 = "4. Salir";

            cout << "MENU DECIMAL" << endl << decimal1 << endl << decimal2 << endl << decimal3 << endl << salir3 << endl;

            do {
                cout << "Digite una opcion :"; cin >> opcion3;
            } while (opcion3 < 1 || opcion3 > 4);

            switch (opcion3) {
                case 1 :
                case 2 :
                case 3 :
                case 4 :
                default : break;
            }
        } break;

        case 3 : 
        { 
            int opcion4;
            string hexa1, hexa2, hexa3, salir4; 

            hexa1 = "1. Pasar de hexadecimal a binario";
            hexa2 = "2. Pasar de hexadecimal a decimal";
            hexa3 = "3. Pasar de hexadecimal a octal";
            salir4 = "4. Salir";

            cout<< "MENU HEXADECIMAL" << endl << hexa1 << endl << hexa2 << endl << hexa3 << endl << salir4 << endl;

            do {
                cout<< "Digite una opcion :"; cin >> opcion4;
            } while (opcion4 < 1 || opcion4 > 4);

            switch (opcion4) {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                default: break;
            }
        } break;

        case 4 :
        {
            int opcion5; 
            string octal1, octal2, octal3, salir5;

            octal1 = "1. Pasar de octal a binario";
            octal2 = "2. Pasar de octal a decimal";
            octal3 = "3. Pasar de octal a hexadecimal";
            salir5 = "4. Salir";

            cout<<"MENU OCTAL"<< endl << octal1 << endl << octal2 << endl << octal3 << endl << salir5 << endl;


            do {
                cout<< "Digite una opcion :"; cin >> opcion5;
            } while (opcion5 < 1 || opcion5 > 4);

            switch (opcion5) {
                case 1 :
                case 2 :
                case 3 :
                case 4 :
                default : break;
            } 
        } break;

        case 5 : return 0;
        default : break;
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Como se menciona en la respuesta de eferion, debes tener buenas prácticas de escritura, ya que la mayoría de los errores son de sintaxis, los más comunes son faltas de `;` al final de la sentencia y ese tipo de cosas.

Trata de tener un mejor control sobre lo que escribes indentando el código y dandole formato especial.

~Saludos!

Comment: Poco que añadir a tu comentario, salvo que `std::endl` suele ser *mal usado*. Es conocido por su bajada de rendimiento ya que *flushea* el stream, aunque en este caso no creo que afecte en nada. Me gusta tu nick cloruro sódico :)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Jajaja gracias. Si se que `std::endl` suele ser mal usado, pero en el código del OP, está llamando a `std::cout` como si no hubiera llamado a `std` al principio, entonces me pareció confuso, por ello le añadí la sugerencia. Aunque yo prefiero usar `\n` _instead_

Comment: Gracias a todos, ya entendi el por que el error, recien empiezo aprender a programar, no se como llamar todavia a una funcion. desde ya gracias por su tiempo dedicado a responder a mi pregunta. :) me andubo :)

Comment: y por los consejos tambien gracias, voy a escribir mas ordenado.

Comment: No hay de que @ShamdelPrado Aquí estaremos todos para ayudarte.

Answer (score 3):

Las variables tienen un contexto que es el que marca su ciclo de vida. Cuando el código abandona el contexto de una variable dicha variable deja de existir:

```
int main()
{
  int a = 0; // El ámbito de esta variable es la función main

  if( a==0 )
  {
    int b = 1; // El ámbito de b es el if
  }

  a = 4; // OK porque seguimos dentro del ámbito de a
  b = 5; // ERROR: b no existe porque hemos abandonado su ámbito
}
```

Las estructura de control de flujo (`if`, `if-else`, `switch`) no crean ámbitos, sino que es necesario crearlos explícitamente y es por ello que detrás de un `if` solemos encontrar una llave de apertura:

```
if( algo )
{ // Inicio del ámbito
  // ...
}  // Fin del ámbito
```

Claro está, el if puede ir sin llaves, pero en ese caso la instrucción únicamente afectará a la instrucción inmediatamente siguiente:

```
if( algo )
  printf("Hola"); // Dentro del if
printf(" Mundo"); // Fuera del if
```

El caso de `switch` es ligeramente diferente. Para entendernos podríamos asumir que `switch` es una especie de alias que se traduce en una suerte de saltos con `goto`.

Un ejemplo de switch:

```
int valor;
// ...
switch( valor )
{
  case 0:
   // ...
   break;

  case 1:
   // ...

  case 2:
  case 3:
    break;

  default:
}

valor = 5;
```

Una posible traducción:

```
int valor;

// ...

if(valor == 0)
  goto CASE0;
else if(valor == 1)
  goto CASE1;
else if(valor == 2)
  goto CASE2;
else if(valor == 3)
  goto CASE 3;
else
  goto FIN;

CASE0:
// ...
goto FIN;

CASE1:
// ...

CASE 2:
CASE 3:
goto FIN;

FIN:
valor = 5;
```

Es decir, el código que metemos en cada case no está encerrado por defecto dentro de un ámbito sino que el programa separa (sin ser demasiado estrictos) las diferentes secciones con saltos. Este comportamiento explica por qué no puedes declarar variables dentro de un `switch` sin usar llaves:

```
int main()
{
  int valor;
  switch( valor )
  {
    case 0:
      int a;

    case 1:
  }
}

int main()
{
  int valor;
  if(valor == 0)
    goto CASE0;
  else if(valor==1)
    goto CASE1;
  else
    goto FIN;

  CASE0:
  int a;

  CASE1:
  // Técnicamente estamos dentro del ámbito de a
  // Sin embargo la misma puede no haber sido declarada.

  FIN:
  // Aquí seguimos dentro del ámbito de a y tenemos el mismo problema
}
```

Sin embargo al introducir las llaves la cosa cambia:

```
int main()
{
  int valor;
  switch( valor )
  {
    case 0:
    {
      int a;
    }
    case 1:
  }
}

int main()
{
  int valor;
  if(valor == 0)
    goto CASE0;
  else if(valor==1)
    goto CASE1;
  else
    goto FIN;

  CASE0:
  {
    int a;
  }

  CASE1:
  // Ya no estamos en el ámbito de a, luego estamos seguros
  // de que aquí no existe

  FIN:
  // Ya no estamos en el ámbito de a, luego estamos seguros
  // de que aquí no existe
}
```

Con esta explicación espero que quede un poco más claro el concepto del ámbito de las variables.

Ahora, si pasamos a tu código vemos lo siguiente (bien tabulado):

```
case 1:
{// Inicio de ámbito.
  int opcion2;
  std::string binario1,binario2,binario3,salir2;// lo mismo con el std:: delante del string y cout.
  binario1 = "1. Pasar de binario a decimal";
  binario2 = "2. Pasar de binario a hexadecimal";
  binario3 = "3. Pasar de binario a octal";
  salir2 = "4. salir";
} // Fin de ámbito, las variables declaradas aquí dentro dejan de existir

// Esta instrucción ya no es válida porque binario1 y compañía
// no existen
std::cout<<"MENU BINARIO"<<endl<<binario1<<endl<<binario2<<endl
                               <<binario3<<endl<<salir2<<endl;
/*bucle dowhile que solo elija una opcion valida*/
do{
  cout<<"Digite una opcion :";cin>>opcion2;
}while (opcion2<1 || opcion2>4);

switch (opcion2){
  case 1 :
  case 2 :
  case 3 :
  case 4 :
  default: break;
}
break;
```

Se ve claramente el origen del problema (el cual está comentado en el código para mayor claridad). Al salir del ámbito donde se han declarado las variables, éstas han dejado de existir y, por tanto, no pueden ser utilizadas.

El problema se soluciona ampliando el ámbito todo lo que necesitemos:

```
case 1:
{// Inicio de ámbito.
  int opcion2;
  std::string binario1,binario2,binario3,salir2;// lo mismo con el std:: delante del string y cout.
  binario1 = "1. Pasar de binario a decimal";
  binario2 = "2. Pasar de binario a hexadecimal";
  binario3 = "3. Pasar de binario a octal";
  salir2 = "4. salir";

  // Como no hemos salido del ámbito, las variables pueden ser usadas.
  std::cout<<"MENU BINARIO"<<endl<<binario1<<endl<<binario2<<endl
                               <<binario3<<endl<<salir2<<endl;
  /*bucle dowhile que solo elija una opcion valida*/
  do{
    cout<<"Digite una opcion :";cin>>opcion2;
  }while (opcion2<1 || opcion2>4);

  switch (opcion2){
    case 1 :
    case 2 :
    case 3 :
    case 4 :
    default: break;
  }
} // Fin de ámbito
break;
```

Aunque la mejor solución sería extraer el contenido del `case` a una función. Es mejor coger buenos hábitos de programación desde el principio.

Un saludo.

Comment: +1 Por el ejemplazo!